# jsdoc doesn't trust @param declarations

Tags: jsdoc

When running jsdoc on the code like the following, the @param docs are ignored. I presume that this is because I'm returning the function within an IIFE, but considering how common a pattern this is in JS, I find it hard to believe that jsdoc can't handle it.

```
/** @namespace */
var util = {
    /**
     * Repeat <tt>str</tt> several times.
     * @param {google.maps.Marker} str The string to repeat.
     * @param {number} [times=1] How many times to repeat the string.
     * @returns {string}
     */
    repeat: (function() {

        var magicNumber = 1;

        return function(str, times) {
            if (times === undefined || times < magicNumber) {
                times = magicNumber;
            }
            return new Array(times+1).join(str);
        };

    }())
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently jsdoc will only include `@param` and `@return` docs if it considers the documented item to be a *function*. You can force this behavior by specifying [`@function`](https://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/wiki/TagFunction) in the doc comment.

So this worked:

```
/** @namespace */
var util = {
    /**
     * Repeat <tt>str</tt> several times.
     * @function <---- ADDED THIS LINE
     * @param {google.maps.Marker} str The string to repeat.
     * @param {number} [times=1] How many times to repeat the string.
     * @returns {string}
     */
    repeat: (function() {

        var magicNumber = 1;

        return function(str, times) {
            if (times === undefined || times < magicNumber) {
                times = magicNumber;
            }
            return new Array(times+1).join(str);
        };

    }())
};
```

(A bit tedious if you ask me. I'd hope jsdoc would either be smart enough to realize it's a function, or simply trust the user without having to add `@function` everywhere.)